# Count maximum nested list items JQuery, Javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have an unordered list with nested lists.
Using Jquery or Javascript, I need to find the maximum count of "second_level_item" list items within all of the nested lists on hover over the "top_level_list" ul.
For example if I hover over the "top_level_list" below, it should output the number 3, because the second nested list contains 3 items, the maximum amount for any of the given nested lists.

```
<ul class="top_level_list">
    <li class="top_level_item">
        <ul class="second_level_list">
            <li class="second_level_item">This list has 1 item - A</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="top_level_item">
        <ul class="second_level_list">
            <li class="second_level_item">This list has 3 items - A</li>
            <li class="second_level_item">This list has 3 items - B</li>
            <li class="second_level_item">This list has 3 items - C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My current code retuns the combined total of all list items within all "second_level_list", therefore it outputs number 4.

```
$(function countMax() {
    $('.top_level_list').hover(
        function () {
            var countMaxItem = $(this).children('.top_level_item').children('.second_level_list').children('.second_level_item').length;
            alert(countMaxItem);
        }, function () {
            //empty
        }
    );
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go through all second_level_list's and then count their second_level_item children, updating the max count counter if it is higher than before.

```
$(function countMax() {
    $('.top_level_list').hover(

    function () {
        maxCount = 0;
        $('.second_level_list', this).each(function (index, secondLevelList) {
            if ($(secondLevelList).children('.second_level_item').length > maxCount) {
                maxCount = $(secondLevelList).children('.second_level_item').length;
            }
        });
        alert(maxCount);
    },

    function () {
        //empty
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var result = Math.max.apply(null, ($('.second_level_list', this).map(function() {
    return $(this).children('li').length;
}));
```

OR

```
var counts = [];
$('.second_level_list', this).each(function() {
    counts.push($(this).children('li').length);
});
var result = Math.max.apply(null, counts);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGAwh/1/)**